# Steinitz' exchange lemma application/exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Today our lin. algebra professor gave us the following exercise to practice Steinitz' exchange lemma: for the following basis and set of vectors, on which vectors can we apply Steinitz' exchange lemma?
\begin{align}
\text{Basis: }& \{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}\\
\text{Set: }& \{(-1,1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,-1)\}\ \text{l.i. (linearly independent)}
\end{align}

I have no idea how to start from here, so I'd appreciate someone helping me out.

Comment: You may start by carefully reading the Steinitz lemma again.

Comment: Always give a reference in order for people who need (at least) to refresh their memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma

Comment: I added a solution. I'd appreciate if you could check it.

Answer (score 1):

Once reread the lemma, I think I know how to solve it (tell me if otherwise).

Firstly, I'll define these six vectors: the basis', $V = \langle (1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1) \rangle \equiv \langle u_1,u_2,u_3 \rangle$, and the set's, $\{(−1,1,1),(1,−1,1),(1,1,−1)\} \equiv \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.

So knowing that $v_i \in V$, we can express the set's vectors as a linear combination of the basis' vector like this:

$$v_i = \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i u_i = \lambda_1(1,0,0)+\lambda_2(1,1,0)+\lambda_3(1,1,1).$$
This can be expressed as a system of equations in which we find the $\lambda$'s:
\begin{cases}
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = v_i \hat{i}\\
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = v_i \hat{j}\\
\lambda_1 = v_i \hat{k}
\end{cases}

The only vector for which one of the three solutions is $\lambda_i = 0$ is $v_1$, specifically $\lambda_2 = 0$, but since we only need the inverse of $\lambda_1$, then there's no problem (at least for the first substitution).

Now we just follow this procedure to express $u_1$ as a lin. comb., taking into account that $\exists(\lambda_1)^{-1}$:
\begin{align}
v_1 =  \lambda_1 u_1 + \lambda_2 u_2 + \lambda_3 u_3 \\\\\
\lambda_1^{-1} v_1 =  u_1 + \lambda_1^{-1}\lambda_2 u_2 + \lambda_1^{-1}\lambda_3 u_3 \\\\
u_1 = \lambda_1^{-1} v_1 - \lambda_1^{-1}\lambda_2 u_2 - \lambda_1^{-1}\lambda_3 u_3 \\\\
\end{align}

This way, notice we could express $u_1$ as a linear combination of $\{v_1, u_2, u_3\}$.

Now what's left is checking whether this basis is l.i.:
\begin{align}
\vec{0} &= \alpha_1 v_1 +\alpha_2 u_2 + \alpha_3 u_3\\
\vec{0} &= \alpha_1 (\lambda_1 u_1+\lambda_2 u_2+\lambda_3 u_3) +\alpha_2 u_2 + \alpha_3 u_3\\
\vec{0} &= \alpha_1\lambda_1 u_1 + (\alpha_1\lambda_2 + \alpha_2) u_2 + (\alpha_1\lambda_3 + \alpha_3) u_3
\end{align}

And so for this basis to be l.i all constants have to be $0$. The only way there is is $\alpha_i = 0, \forall i$.

What's left is repeating the same process for the two left, $v_2$ and $v_3$.